# move the results from openrowset method into Temp table in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

With

```
DECLARE @testVariable uniqueidentifier; 
SET @testVariable ='c0cad38f-da93-46b5-9f90-ff9eea7dbfd8'; 
DECLARE @qry varchar(2000);



SET @qry = 'SELECT * into #REPORT_1 FROM OPENROWSET
 ( ''SQLNCLI'', 
''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
 '' SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC VDMS_DB.dbo.UspRankingOfNonNegotiables4 ''''' + cast(@testVariable as varchar(100)) + ''''''')' 


exec(@qry) 

select * from #REPORT_1
```

I'm getting error like this

> Invalid object name '#REPORT_1'.

Please suggest me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, Remove dynamic SQL and made it as static by including test variable value directly in your openrowset statement.
declare @parameter uniqueidentifier

Method-1

```
SELECT *
INTO #REPORT_1
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;', ' SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC VDMS_DB.dbo.UspRankingOfNonNegotiables4 @parameter')

SELECT *
FROM #REPORT_1
```

Method-2

Create your #Report_1 temporary table separately then do Insert into exec.. like the below.

```
Create table #REPORT_1
(
col datatype1,
...
...
)

DECLARE @testVariable UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

SET @testVariable = 'c0cad38f-da93-46b5-9f90-ff9eea7dbfd8';

DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(2000);

SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
 ( ''SQLNCLI'', 
''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
 '' SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC VDMS_DB.dbo.UspRankingOfNonNegotiables4 ''''' + cast(@testVariable AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''''''')'

Insert into #REPORT_1 (col,....)
EXEC (@qry)

select *from #REPORT_1
```

Method-3

```
DECLARE @testVariable UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

SET @testVariable = 'c0cad38f-da93-46b5-9f90-ff9eea7dbfd8';

DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(2000);

SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
 ( ''SQLNCLI'', 
''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',
 '' SET FMTONLY OFF EXEC VDMS_DB.dbo.UspRankingOfNonNegotiables4 ''''' + cast(@testVariable AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''''''')'

SELECT *
INTO #REPORT_1
EXEC (@qry)

SELECT *
FROM #REPORT_1
```

Comment: @Gopal Yadav: I updated my answer, please refer Method-2

Comment: thank u ,but i need solution without creating Temporary table.moving the results directly into temp table,

Answer (score 0):

> This works

```
select * into #temp_my1 from openrowset
('SQLNCLI','Server=DEV-WKST-136;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'EXEC performancev3.dbo.usp_testa')

select * from #temp_my1
```

> this doesnt work...

```
declare @query nvarchar(4000)
set @query='select * into #temp_my2 from openrowset
(''SQLNCLI'',''Server=DEV-WKST-136;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ''EXEC performancev3.dbo.usp_testa'')'

exec(@query)

select * from #temp_my2
```

Why ...?Because exec statements executes in a seperate session context other than your current session.